# Html 5 History API

Tags: javascript, html5-history-api

Как при открытии блока на странице менять  `Url` в строке браузера с `/index` на `/login` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
history.pushState(null, 'Login', 'login.php');
```

или

```
history.replaceState(null, 'Login', 'login.php');
```

Первый метод добавляет элемент в историю, второй - заменяет текущий

http://habrahabr.ru/post/123106/